# Validating a date using JCalender

Tags: java, validation, date

I'm trying to make it so when I enter an invalid date or anything other than the set standard values (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) I get an error that tells me that I've put in an invalid input. The actual outcome I get now is that it throws an exception.

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            final String start_1 = (((JTextField)dateChooser_1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(start ,format);
            LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.now();
```

---datechooser code

```
    JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();

    dateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateChooser.setBounds(71, 112, 175, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser);
```

--- full class code

public class View {

Controller bereken = new Controller();
    private JFrame frame;

```
public void Programma() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                View window = new View();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public View() {
    Initialize();
}
private void Initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLocale(Locale.US);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 751, 523);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();

    dateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateChooser.setBounds(71, 112, 175, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser);

    JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
    chooser.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(
        new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                if ("date".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
                    System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()
                        + ": " + (Date) e.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        });

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Years");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  bereken.berekenVerschilInJaren(start)+" Jaar");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(259, 391, 173, 52);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Months");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  bereken.berekenVerschilInMaanden(start)+" Maanden");

        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(62, 392, 173, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Days");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  bereken.berekenVerschilInDagen(start)+" Dagen");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton_2.setBounds(259, 330, 173, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

    JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Hours");
    btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  bereken.berekenVerschilInUren(start)+" Uren");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton_3.setBounds(62, 330, 173, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_3);

    JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("Seconds");
    btnNewButton_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  bereken.berekenVerschilInSeconden(start)+" Seconden");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton_4.setBounds(257, 267, 175, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_4);

    JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("Milliseconds");
    btnNewButton_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  bereken.berekenVerschilInMilliseconden(start)+" milliseconden");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewButton_5.setBounds(62, 267, 173, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_5);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Your selected Primary date in:");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(64, 211, 403, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblVoerJeGeboorte = new JLabel("Select Primary Date:");
    lblVoerJeGeboorte.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblVoerJeGeboorte.setBounds(74, 83, 272, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblVoerJeGeboorte);

    JDateChooser dateChooser_1 = new JDateChooser();
    dateChooser_1.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateChooser_1.setBounds(502, 112, 175, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser_1);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Select Secondary Date:");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    label.setBounds(510, 83, 272, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    JButton btnNewButton_6 = new JButton("Calculate Difference");
    btnNewButton_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final String start = (((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            final String start_1 = (((JTextField)dateChooser_1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse(start ,format);
            LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.now();

            long Datum_1 = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(startDate, endDate);
            long Datum_2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
            long Datum_3 = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startDate, endDate);
            long Datum_4 = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(startDate, endDate);
            long Datum_5 = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startDate, endDate);

            DateTimeFormatter format_1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime startDate_1 = LocalDateTime.parse(start_1 ,format_1);
            LocalDateTime endDate_1 = LocalDateTime.now();  

            long Datum_6 = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(startDate_1, endDate_1);
            long Datum_7 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate_1, endDate_1);
            long Datum_8 = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startDate_1, endDate_1);
            long Datum_9 = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(startDate_1, endDate_1);
            long Datum_10 = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startDate_1, endDate_1);

            long Jaren = Datum_6 - Datum_1;
            long Dagen = Datum_7 - Datum_2;
            long Uren = Datum_8 - Datum_3;
            long Seconden = Datum_9 - Datum_4;
            long milliseconden = Datum_10 - Datum_5;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  Jaren+ " Jaar, "+ Dagen+ " Dagen, "+ Uren+ " Uren, "+ Seconden+ " Seconden, "+ milliseconden+ " milliseconden");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnNewButton_6.setBounds(280, 83, 187, 67);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_6);




}
```

}

--- console outcome

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'dsadasda' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at View$9.actionPerformed(View.java:164)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Does it throw an exception when you give it bad input?  Because if so, you can use that with a try-catch block.

Comment: What is wrong with this code?  What is the expected vs actual outcome?  Give us the input.

Comment: Yeah it does throw the exception, I tried adding a try-catch block and it still gave me the same response.

Comment: I'm expecting my console to give me a message or error saying that the input was invalid due to having put in something other than what required. 

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'dsadasda' could not be parsed at index 0
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
 at View$9.actionPerformed(View.java:164)

Here you can see I typed in some random characters in my input to test,